# Attaching tooltip to checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For the following table:

```
<table>                    
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="true" />
        Select something
      </label>
    </td>

    <td>
      <label for="select">
        <select name="select" id="select">
        <option value="Default"></option>
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
      </label>
    <td>
  </tr>
```

I'm trying to attach a conditional that if it's checked and 'default' is selected on the dropdown, for tooltip to show message 'error'.

My jquery so far:

```
if ($("#check").is(":checked")) {  
  $select = $("#select");
  if ($select.val() == "Default") {
    $select.addClass("ui-tooltip"({ content: "error" }));                     
  }
}
```

CSS for tooltip:

```
.ui-tooltip  
{  
   background: #FFFCC; 
   border: 1px solid blue;        
}
```

Comment: Is there a condition you want to check if checkbox is checked?

Comment: If it's checked with any other value from the dropdown, no need for error message

Comment: your addClass line seems messed up. "ui-tooltip"({ content: "error" }),  you need to pass a string to addClass but you randomly have the ({content: error } pased in to addClass as well.     Also, im not sure if you expect this to happen when the values are changed. You need to use the change event to re-evaluate your code because right now it's just going to run once when the page is loaded. (unless there is more code you didnt post)

Comment: It is not magically going to bind it self when the check box becomes checked or when the select is changed.

Comment: Your add class method is messed up as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the value in the select evverytime a user clicks the check box you have to attach an **.change()** event handler, or else your browser won't know when to run the function. Something like:

```
$('#check').change(function(){
    if ($("#check").is(":checked")) {  
        $select = $("#select");
        if ($select.val() == "Default") {
            $select.addClass("ui-tooltip");                     
        }
     }
})
```

This tells your browser to run the function and check the value in the select box everytime you change the value in the input element with an id of **check**(your checkbox in this instance). If you want to add some custom content to it you might have to do a little more jquery code.

**Note how the add class method looks as well. I'm not sure you can add content from there, could be wrong though**